# Troubles with Translating a VBA Function to Dart

Tags: excel, vba, flutter, dart

It has now been weeks that I have tried to translate this simple looking function into dart. I have the function working in Dart, but it returns the wrong result. I have tried different variations and strategies to find what is going wrong. I just have no idea about VBA so it is hard. Maybe if I could put print statements in the VBA code and see what gets printed at each stage then maybe I could deduce further but I have no clue how to do this or how to read the print statements(like where do I read them?). Could someone help me try to figure this out or help me with strategies to debug? My last attempt was to just use regular Excel functions and use cells to hold the values and the final result was the exact result I get in Dart! So this further confuses things. I know the VBA code is giving the correct answer because the book with the actual math functions says the VBA codes gives the right result but the Dart code(and apparently just trying to use regular Excel functions and cells) gives the wrong result.

Here is the VBA code:

```
Function CND(X As Double) As Double
    Dim y As Double, Exponential As Double, SumA As Double, SumB As Double
    
    y = Abs(X)
    If y > 37 Then
        CND = 0
    Else
        Exponential = Exp(-y ^ 2 / 2)
        If y < 7.07106781186547 Then
            SumA = 3.52624965998911E-02 * y + 0.700383064443688
            SumA = SumA * y + 6.37396220353165
            SumA = SumA * y + 33.912866078383
            SumA = SumA * y + 112.079291497871
            SumA = SumA * y + 221.213596169931
            SumA = SumA * y + 220.206867912376
            SumB = 8.83883476483184E-02 * y + 1.75566716318264
            SumB = SumB * y + 16.064177579207
            SumB = SumB * y + 86.7807322029461
            SumB = SumB * y + 296.564248779674
            SumB = SumB * y + 637.333633378831
            SumB = SumB * y + 793.826512519948
            SumB = SumB * y + 440.413735824752
            CND = Exponential * SumA / SumB
        Else
            SumA = y + 0.65
            SumA = y + 4 / SumA
            SumA = y + 3 / SumA
            SumA = y + 2 / SumA
            SumA = y + 1 / SumA
            CND = Exponential / (SumA * 2.506628274631)
        End If
  End If
  
  If X > 0 Then CND = 1 - CND

End Function
```

Here is the Dart function:

```
double cnd (double x) {
  double y;
  double exponential;
  double sumA;
  double sumB;
  double value;
  

  y = x.abs();
  if (y > 37) {
    value = 0;
  } else {
    exponential = exp(pow(-y, 2) / 2);
    if (y < 7.07106781186547) {
      sumA = 3.52624965998911E-02 * y + 0.700383064443688;
      sumA = sumA * y + 6.37396220353165;
      sumA = sumA * y + 33.912866078383;
      sumA = sumA * y + 112.079291497871;
      sumA = sumA * y + 221.213596169931;
      sumA = sumA * y + 220.206867912376;
      sumB = 8.83883476483184E-02 * y + 1.75566716318264;
      sumB = sumB * y + 16.064177579207;
      sumB = sumB * y + 86.7807322029461;
      sumB = sumB * y + 296.564248779674;
      sumB = sumB * y + 637.333633378831;
      sumB = sumB * y + 793.826512519948;
      sumB = sumB * y + 440.413735824752;
      value = exponential * (sumA / sumB);
    } else {
      sumA = y + 0.65;
      sumA = y + 4 / sumA;
      sumA = y + 3 / sumA;
      sumA = y + 2 / sumA;
      sumA = y + 1 / sumA;
      value = exponential / (sumA * 2.506628274631);
    }
  }

  if (x > 0) {
    value = 1 - value;
  }
  return value;
  }
```

Here is the Excel screenshot of my attempt of just using Excel functions and cells:

[image: Excel_ScreenShot]

The code `=CND(-0.3253)` returns [image: Excel_VBA_Result] in Excel with the VBA code. In Dart, the code `cnd(-0.3253);` returns 0.4140535951706531 which is the same result that the Excel representation of the function gives that is shown in the image. What is going on?

Comment: Not familiar with Dart, but, in VBA, exponentiation has a higher precedence than negation, so `-10^2/2` => `-50`.  Most likely, the Dart `pow` function would be equivalent to VBA `(-10)^2/2` => `+50`

Comment: Yes thank you. It was an issue with the pow function!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the VBA result is the correct, your Dart code should probably read:

```
exponential = exp(-pow(y, 2) / 2);
```

Comment: I cannot thank you enough. You have just changed my life! I hope your life gets blessed!